# SAP UI5 Object List item with "title" as hyperlink

Tags: sapui5

Please suggest Object List Item "title" with hyperlink and on click of it, should navigate to some url in a new tab.

```xml
<List items="{ path: 'sonarReport>/measures' }"
        id="sonarRepId"
        mode="SingleSelectMaster" 
        selectionChange="onChange"
        updateFinished="onFinsihed">            
    <ObjectListItem icon="{sonarReport>imageL}"
            **title="{sonarReport>value}"**
            class="sonarCustom"
            type="Active">
        <attributes>
            <ObjectAttribute text="{sonarReport>metric}"></ObjectAttribute>
        </attributes>
        <firstStatus>
            <ObjectStatus title="{sonarReport>state}"
                icon="{sonarReport>image}"
                state="Success"></ObjectStatus>
        </firstStatus>
    </ObjectListItem>               
</List>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can opt to extend the ObjectListItem like this

```js
  ObjectListItem.extend("ObjectListItemEx", {
    metadata: {
      events: {
        titlePress: {}
      }
    },
    renderer: {},
    onAfterRendering: function() {
      if (ObjectListItem.prototype.onAfterRendering) {
        ObjectListItem.prototype.onAfterRendering.apply(this, arguments);
      }
      var that = this;
      this.$().find(".sapMObjLTitle").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.click(function() {
          that.fireTitlePress();
        });
        $this.css("cursor", "pointer");
      });
    }
  });
```

demo: https://jsbin.com/hofumej/1/edit?js,output

Comment: can't we do it using FormattedText ? just curios if we can , something like setting an id , get by id , setTitle(new FormattedText(.....)) why this won't work sir ?

Comment: I do not know how to do this neatly.

Comment: I think this extension is as neat as it gets. Although from a usability point of view it's not very clear to the user that he can click on the title.

Comment: I have replaced it with Custom List Item and it is very flexible to place different items.

Answer (score 1):

I have replaced it with Custom List Item and it is very flexible to place different items.